# How to write a function that returns image height and width, without using image onload?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, image, dom

I need to use image height and width to scale my canvas, i was trying to find a way to do it without image onload, because i don't want the values losing after writing a code outside of the img onload scope. I found a way as i wrote below, but it sometimes works and sometimes does not and my calculated values seems to be calculated as infinity because it sometimes gives the value of 0 as the image height.

```
getImageSrc() {
    const imgSrc = this.fileHandler(this.image._id, 'image')
    return imgSrc
  }
  getImageWidth(): number {
    const img = this.createImageObj()
    const imgWidth = img.naturalWidth
    return imgWidth
  }
  createImageObj(): HTMLImageElement {
    const imgSrc = this.getImageSrc()
    const imgObj = new Image()
    imgObj.src = imgSrc
    return imgObj
  }
  getImageHeight(): number {
    const img = this.createImageObj()
    const imgHeight = img.naturalHeight
    return imgHeight
  }
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new image every time?

Answer (score 1):

Make your class take an image object instead:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(private image: Image) {}
}
```

Then create an async function to wrap the onload into a promise:

```
async function createMyClass(src: string) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = src;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        img.onload = () => resolve(new MyClass(img)); // img done loading
        img.onerror = (err) => reject(err); // err occured
    });
}
```

This is called ["promisifying"](https://javascript.info/promisify).

Your methods can then be changed to work around the given image:

```
getImageSrc() {
    return this.image.src;
}

getImageWidth() {
    return this.image.width;
}

getImageHeight() {
    return this.image.height;
}
```

---

If you so prefer, you could also make `image` a "hash field" to make it truly private:

```
class MyClass {
    #image: Image;
    constructor(image: Image) { this.#image = image; }
}
```

And you could also make the async function a static factory method instead:

```
static async createMyClass(src: string) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your great explainations, i refactored my code like on this codepen https://codepen.io/burcuicen/pen/eYrKxXV, but now i am getting the error of `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getImageHeight')` i know the problem, i should somehow initialize the class. What am i doing wrong, can you help?

Comment: @CedricSmith I meant for everything in this answer to be added onto your existing class, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5Ly0w).

Comment: Canvas Initiator class is actually huge, I just included some of the code, I did not really understand where to use createCanvasInitiator class, is there an easy way of getting the image height and width? @caTS